# Excel macro to transpose data from one sheet to another based column name and cell content

Tags: vba, excel

I have a worksheet1 with a column labeled participant and columns labeled 1-20 (experiment ID numbers).

I have another worksheet2 with data of participants (column) and the experiments (column) they participated in. In the cells under the experiment column, there are multiple experiment ID numbers as participants have participated in multiple experiments. For example a cell could read, "1,4,5".

What I need to do is place an "X", on worksheet1, in the corresponding cells from worksheet2. For example, a cell reading "1,4,5" for participant "003" from worksheet2 would place an "X" in the columns labelled 1, 4, 5 in worksheet1.

I hope this is clear. I am completely new to macros but need help with this as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0):

This is your lucky day.  I'm going to walk you through how to do this, with some code.  But you have to understand the concepts in order to benefit from it.  If you do, you can apply these ideas to many projects.

First, you will need to break down the tasks into manageable easy steps.  Macros aren't going to help you because of all the different scenarios.  Let's break it down into steps, then address how to accomplish each.

Before we get started, consider the Sheets("worksheet1").Cells(row#, col#) format.  This allows you to move through cells on a sheet by incrementing the row number and column number using variables.
In this case, oRow (original Row), nRow (new Row), etc.

1. Look at the Participant row on worksheet2.  : participant = Sheets("worksheet2").Cells(oRow, 1)
2. Copy the Participant to worksheet1 Column 1.  :  Sheets("worksheet1").Cells(nRow, 1) = participant
3. Split the experiments cell into a list:   Split(Sheets("worksheet2").Cells(oRow, 2), ",")
4. Loop through the list items and for each one, put an "X" under the column of the same name.
5. Repeat steps 1-4 for each row (participant entry) on worksheet2.

Declare your variables. In this case, I'm declaring them outside of the method because I am using them in two methods.

```
Dim lastRow1 As Integer
Dim lastRow2 As Integer
Dim lastCol1 As Integer
```

Now the method.

```
Sub ExperimentMover()

Dim expList() As String
Dim nRow As Integer
Dim oRow As Integer
Dim participant As String
Dim iCol As Integer

    Call GetLastRows
    nRow = lastRow1 + 1

    'Loop through the contents on Worksheet2 one Row at a time
    For oRow = 2 To lastRow2

        'Get the Participant and store it as a variable.
        participant = Sheets("worksheet2").Cells(oRow, 1)
        'Create a list of the items in the experiments cell, splitting using ","
        expList = Split(Sheets("worksheet2").Cells(oRow, 2), ",")

        'Set the participant in worksheet1
        Sheets("worksheet1").Cells(nRow, 1) = participant

        For Each experiment In expList

            'Loop through each column on worksheet1
            For iCol = 2 To lastCol1
                'Set the column Name and then check it to see if it matches Experiment
                colName = Sheets("worksheet1").Cells(1, iCol).Text
                If colName = experiment Then
                    Sheets("worksheet1").Cells(nRow, iCol) = "X"
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next iCol
        Next experiment

    'Increment the row number on worksheet1.  It should be matching the row on worksheet2
    nRow = nRow + 1

    Next oRow

End Sub
```

Here is the GetLastRows subroutine.  I like to separate it because there are many times I need to call it in a project.  It's better to just have a method that you can test and verify works, then if you have to change something, you change one thing.  Instead of 15 calls and maybe miss one.

```
Private Sub GetLastRows()

lastRow1 = Sheets("worksheet1").Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row
lastRow2 = Sheets("worksheet2").Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row
lastCol1 = Sheets("worksheet1").Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

End Sub
```

[image: Screenshot of worksheet2]

[image: Screenshot of worksheet1]

Edit:  Formatting Fix with Code Indentation

Comment: There is some extra code that you could eliminate, but it isn't costing much more to do it this way, and it's much easier on the eye to see a variable name instead of a long expression.  For example, you don't need the variable colName at all.  I know seeing it like that helped my brain when I was just starting (and still).

take this for example.

instead of 
Split(Sheets("worksheet1").Cells(oRow, 2), ",") -------
you can use ----------
origString = Sheets("worksheet1").Cells(oRow, 2)  -----
Split(origString, ",")

Comment: Feel free to mark posts as the answer in the future, it helps to let future users know which solutions to focus on right away.